# Sitecore DEF - Get the total data count

Tags: data-exchange-framework

We would like to log the total records fetched from databases in `Data Exchange Framework` and log it in log files. How we can get the total count?

Answer (score 1):

For this, you need to add a `Pipeline step` under your `Pipeline`. This is called `Iterate Data and Run Pipelines Pipeline Step`, which will be created from the template called `Iterate Data and Run Pipelines Pipeline Step`.

The location of this template is

```
/sitecore/templates/Data Exchange/Framework/Pipeline Steps/Iterate Data and Run Pipelines Pipeline Step
```

The code is already written in the `Processor`, which will log the number of items processed. The following code is implemented for this.

```
if (iterableData == null)
{
    this.Log(new Action<string>(logger.Debug), pipelineContext, "Iterable data is null.", Array.Empty<string>());
}
else
{
    int count = 0;
    try
    {
         Action<object> afterElementHandled = (Action<object>) (element => ++count);
         MultithreadedOperationSettings plugin = pipelineStep.GetPlugin<MultithreadedOperationSettings>();
         if (plugin == null ? this.IterateWithoutThreads(iterableData, pipelinesSettings.Pipelines, afterElementHandled, pipelineStep, pipelineContext, logger) : this.IterateWithThreads(plugin, iterableData, pipelinesSettings.Pipelines, afterElementHandled, pipelineStep, pipelineContext, logger))
              this.Log(new Action<string>(logger.Debug), pipelineContext, string.Format("{0} elements were iterated.", (object) count), Array.Empty<string>());
         else
              this.Log(new Action<string>(logger.Info), pipelineContext, string.Format("{0} elements were iterated before the processor was interrupted.", (object) count), Array.Empty<string>());
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            this.LogException(ex, new Action<string>(logger.Error), pipelineContext, "Exception while iterating data.", Array.Empty<string>());
            pipelineContext.CriticalError = true;
          }
    }
}
```

Also if you want to override the logic, then you can create your own `Processor` class and copy the code from the OOTB class, do your changes, and bind your new `Processor` under the `Iterate Data and Run Pipelines Pipeline Step` item in the field called `Processor Type` under the section `Data Exchange Framework`.

Hope this help.